# Quando é que se começou a chamar "meia" ao "6" no Brasil?

Tags: português-brasileiro, origem-histórica

Eu já sabia que é comum no Brasil dizer *meia* no lugar de *seis*, como em números de telefone: *meu número é nove-um-três-meia-quatro*… Lembrei-me hoje disso ao ‘folhear’ o semanário [lisboeta *Sempre Fixe* de 23 de dezembro de 1926, p. 6](http://hemerotecadigital.cm-lisboa.pt/Periodicos/SempreFixe/1926/Dezembro/N33/N33_master/JPG/SempreFixe19126N33_0005_branca_t0.jpg), que propõe nomes alternativos para os algarismos:

> O 6, que para os brasileiros é o *meia dúzia,* será para nós o—*pescadinha de rabo na bôca*.

Quando é que isto começou? Também já se disse *meia dúzia* em números de telefone, *meu número é o nove-um-três-meia dúzia-quatro*… ?

Comment: Para não confundir o 3 com o 6 na fala usa-se meia dúzia, principalmente ao usar telefone que não se vê a pronuncia facial.

Comment: Jacinto, http://www.tirodeletra.com.br/piadas/Trocandoseispormeaiduzia.htm  É uma anedota mas é assim mesmo por estas bandas de cá.

Answer (score 7):

Quando nos referimos a dígitos, o uso de "meia" ao invés de "seis" em pt-BR falado, generalizou-se quando o telefone chegou ao Brasil no início do século XX. Antes disso, é de se supor que já fosse usado toda vez que alguém estivesse ditando números em alguma atividade séria, e que não admitisse erros como:

- A "o número de série é 4687"
- B "quatro, três, oito, sete?"
- A "Não, quatro **seis**. Quatro **meia**", aqui já como uma redução de meia-dúzia.

Ao telefone, não visualizamos o movimento dos lábios e fica mais fácil confundir três e seis.

A fim de evitar que o número seis fosse confundido com o três em uma conversa, passamos a usar o "meia-dúzia", que logo foi reduzido a "meia".

Jà usávamos, há muitos anos, "meia" como redução de "meia hora" ao dizermos "às nove e meia da manhã" ou "à meia-noite e meia", e ainda como redução de de "meia entrada".

Entretanto, nem sempre podemos usar "meia" ao invés de "seis". Veja por exemplo:

- Meu filho tem seis anos.
- Faço anos no dia seis de fevereiro.
- Abram seus livros na página seis.

Isso porque "meia" refere-se ao dígito e não à quantidade.

ADDENDUM - Em situações onde o locutor quer ter a certeza de que todos entenderão o número corretamente, costuma-se dizer mesmo "meia-dúzia", como por exemplo durante um jogo de víspora, em que o número é cantado da seguinte forma: "sessenta e oito, meia-dúzia oito" de modo que fica praticamente impossível alguém confundir três com seis.

Comment: Como é que sabes que foi com os telefones no início de sXX? Tu já tens alardeado a tua idade avançada, mas não há de ser tão avançada assim:) Então com dinheiro, *meia* é 5?

Comment: É pá, ninguém falou em downvotes. Mas sabes que eu gosto de fontes, citações e isso. Aliás também me parece plausível que os telefones tenham contribuído para popularizar este uso. Já tinha a ideia que *meia* referenciava o algarismo e não uma quantidade (aí só mesmo *meia dúzia*); mas sei lá, seria usado também em números de identificação de documentos, soldados?

Comment: Nas feiras de verduras/frutas/legumes já se usava meia dúzia por conta das porções, a fim de se evitar um papo de maluco de se confundir 3 e 6 entre o vendedor e o comprador.

Comment: @Stafusa    Quando escrevi que esse uso "generalizou-se", eu quis dizer "popularizou-se".  Infelizmente não encontrei fontes ou referências na ocasião em que escrevi a resposta.

Comment: @Centaurus Imagino que não sejam mesmo fácil de achar. Incluí a nota por consistência - tendo acabado de colocar a mesma nota numa nova resposta aqui.

Answer (score 0):

O mercado de frutas sempre precisou de referências fixas para definir valores, e as bananas eram o alimento mais barato, tanto que se diz pra algo bem econômico que ele tem preço de banana, sendo assim, e também por conta de as pencas de bananas terem em média 12 frutas ou seja, uma dúzia, quando alguém precisava comprar metade da penca se dizia que queria meia dúzia, ou seja, 6 bananas. Por extensão isso passou a se referir também a outros gêneros, como o telefone e o relógio, isso claro, na língua portuguesa.

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas — por exemplo com referências.

Answer (score 0):

Os **ovos** são geralmente vendidos em caixas com 12 unidades, que se chama "Uma dúzia", para comprar metade disso se usa "meia dúzia" onde o "**meia**" se refere **metade de 12**, ou seja **6 unidades**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).